# LINQ query through Azure blobs of IEnumerable(Of IListBlobItem)

Tags: linq, azure, casting, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find specific `Uri.AbsolutePath` for the Block blob by its name. Azure Storage container contains only Block blobs. List of blobs returned from storage is `IEnumerable(Of IListBlobItem)`.

I use FirstOrDefault to find specific blob by its name. Compiler says there is no Name property for CloudBlockBlob. This is probably related to single blob item type. Even if I use CloudBlockBlob within FirstOrDefault it is still IListBlobItem, thus Name property is missing. How to tackle this in an efficient way?

```
Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Storage connection string")
Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
Dim BlobList As IEnumerable(Of IListBlobItem) = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ContainerName").ListBlobs
Path= If(BlobList.FirstOrDefault(Function(CloudBlockBlob) CloudBlockBlob.Name = "ABC.pdf")?.Uri.AbsolutePath, "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `FirstOrDefault` will result in an `IListBlobItem` according to intellisense but it has of course an actual implementation. Any debugger will tell you what actual type is returned.

In your case you are only interested in the results of `ListBlobs` that are actual of type `CloudBlockBlob`. To do that you can use the [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)  method:

```
Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Storage connection string")
Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
Dim BlobList As IEnumerable(Of CloudBlockBlob) = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ContainerName").ListBlobs.OfType(Of CloudBlockBlob)
Path = If(BlobList.FirstOrDefault(Function(CloudBlockBlob) CloudBlockBlob.Name = "ABC.pdf")?.Uri.AbsolutePath, "")
```

You can probably improve you search by filtering items out on the server side using the `prefix` option of `ListBlobs`

```
Dim BlobList As IEnumerable(Of CloudBlockBlob) = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ContainerName").ListBlobs(prefix := "ABC.pdf").OfType(Of CloudBlockBlob)
```

This line will only list blobs of which the name starts with / equals to "ABC.pdf".

Disclaimer: I am not a VB.Net developer so there might me some small mistakes and some room for readability improvements.